# Fails to distribute my app: “Your app contains non-public API usage.”

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, nszombieenabled

When I upload my app to App Store, there is following error:

> Your app contains non-public API usage. Please review the errors,
>   correct them, and resubmit your application. The app references
>   non-public symbols in Payload/XXX.app/XXX: NSZombieEnabled

XXX is the app name.

I've search the entire project, and didn't find any this keyword (`NSZombieEnabled`). How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into the Build Settings of both your Project and Target?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 4):

Check the ***scheme*** of your app target for the ***Enable zombie objects*** check field. Your production code should not contain `NSZombieEnabled`. So uncheck this for *release* mode

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you need to find the usage of this API's in your code. That's not part of the SDK Code.
It appears to me that you have tried to use APIs which are not declared in your code or have a mismatch against the original declaration.
That's a simple programming fault.

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode, go to edit scheme of your target, in Run section, choose "Diagnostics" tab. You will file Enable Zoombie Objects.